# CO data collection giving a solid color image even on ROI

Tags: google-earth-engine, air-quality

I have been trying to collect carbon monoxide data for Lephalale in Limpopo, South Africa, using the code below. When I run it, it gives me an image with a solid color.

If I use the same code for nitrogen dioxide data collection, it does show the column density of the gas in Lephalale, my ROI.

What could be the problem?

```js
// Load the Sentinel-5P TROPOMI CO dataset.
var s5p = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_CO')
  .select('CO_column_number_density');  // Updated band name

// Define the region of interest (Limpopo, South Africa).
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(28.0, -24.0, 30.5, -21.5);  // Bounding box for Limpopo

// Set the date range.
var startDate = ee.Date('2018-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2018-12-31');

// Filter the dataset based on the date and region.
var filtered = s5p.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(roi);

// Compute the mean CO value for the filtered dataset.
var coMean = filtered.mean();

// Set visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.1,  // Adjust the max value if needed
  palette: 'black, blue, purple, cyan, green, yellow, red'
};

// Display the CO mean image on the map.
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);  // Center the map on the ROI
Map.addLayer(coMean.clip(roi), visParams, 'CO Mean');

// Print the CO mean image metadata.
print(coMean);
```

Comment: Probably a symbology issue. Try adjusting the min, max value in vis_Params